# Применить атрибут для всех свойств класса

Tags: c#

Имеется атрибут `[Browsable()]` который указывает показать это свойство или скрыть его. То есть к нему нельзя будет обратиться даже из классов наследников так, как будто его не существует, но на самом деле оно есть и можно переопределить это свойство в классе наследнике как `[Browsable(true)]`, а в базовом классе `[Browsable(false)]`.

Так как атрибут применяется по каждому свойству по отдельности то не особо удобно в каждом наследнике писать `[Browsable(true)]` чтобы снова отображать свойства. Можно ли применить атрибут ко всем свойствам сразу?

Применение его сразу на класс не помогло.

```
// [Browsable(false)] - не помогло
public class Base
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual string field1 { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual int field2 { get; set; }
}

public class child1 : Base
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override string field1 { get; set; }
}

public class child2 : Base
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override int field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: К свойству можно обращаться, его только IDE не подсказывает. Код успешно компилируется и выполняется.

Comment: @Monk не совсем верно, мы проверили это на модели данных и отобразили в таблице типа GridControl в WPF, 
при выставлении этого свойства колонка даже не появляется в таблице, а без этого свойства и даже если оно virtual то колонка все равно появляется в таблице но пустое

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14663763/5045688. Кроме того, можно с помощью AOP (PostSharp и альтернативы) добиться желаемого. Но это будет оправдано только если на сотни классов/свойств нужно навесить атрибуты. В ином случае проще сделать вручную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `Browsable` предназначен только для отдельных свойств и событий (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=netframework-4.8)). Аналогов, которые бы применялись к классу целиком, нет (во всяком случае я не находил).

Comment: Понял спасибо, мы тоже уже потом поняли что атрибуты пишутся под конкретные типы